# ASP Textbox CSS and Data Binding Expression Issue

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP Textbox and I'm trying to add the style **calDatePicker** along with a databinding expression within the same CssClass attribute.

Below is an example of the code I am trying to get to work. Any ideas?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateValue" CssClass='<%# ShowFieldRequired(Eval("Required"))%>  + "calDatePicker"' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try:

```
CssClass='<%# ShowFieldRequired(Eval("Required"))%> calDatePicker'
```

Or:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateValue" CssClass='<%# ShowFieldRequired(Eval("Required")) + " calDatePicker"%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close. Just move the style inside of the server tag.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateValue" CssClass='<%# ShowFieldRequired(Eval("Required")) + " calDatePicker"%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```